# How to pass more than one argument in the same property in maven command line

Tags: maven, cmd

I'm trying to run automation test using maven command.
my property for running a specific test is -DtestsToExecute
I can run a single test by passing the test name to this property:

```
mvn clean verify -DtestsToExecute=UITest
```

How can I run more than one test at once? I mean how can I pass more than one argument to the same property? I've tried putting comma between the different tests name, but with no success:

```
mvn clean verify -DtestsToExecute=UITest1,UITest2
```

Comment: What is this plugin taking a `testsToExecute` as parameter? It isn't any of the standard Maven plugins.

Comment: I'm using maven in order to run junit UI automation tests which is using the selenium jar. 
By the way, I can run all the tests at once by: -DtestsToExecute=.*UITest